# fail on match in scala fastparse

Tags: scala, fastparse

I have the following [fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/) parser named "variable":

```
val alphabet = 'A' to 'z'
val variable: Parser[String] = P(CharsWhileIn(alphabet).!)
```

I would like for this parser to fail on a specific word like "end",
while still returning a Parser[String].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [negative lookahead](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#NegativeLookahead):

```
val alphabet = 'A' to 'Z'
val variable: P[String] = P(!"end" ~ CharIn(alphabet).rep(min = 1)).!
```

where this will succeed:

```
println( variable.parse("ABCend") )   // Success(ABC,3)
```

but this won't:

```
println( variable.parse("endABC") )   // Failure(!("end"):1:4 ..."ABC")
```